# Get status API for masspay does not return row data while request is in pending status

Tags: transactions, status, dwolla, masspay

I use Dwolla masspay API to submit a payment request with a user_job_id. Upon request submission, I call API (https://masspay.dwollalabs.com/api/status/) to get job details by user_job_id. I hope I can get the transaction IDs from the row data and record the Dwolla transaction IDs in my system. The hope is to be able to handle Dwolla callback for transaction status update using Dowlla transaciton ID for each row.

The problem is that it seems when payment is still in PENDING mode, the job details API call does not return any row level details, therefore I can not get the row level transaction ID. As a result, I can not handle Dwolla callbak for status update because I don't know the transaction ID.

Is there any way for me to corelate the status update call back to the masspay request on my end?

Answer (score 0):

When a job is in Pending mode, it's not possible to view the transaction IDs of the rows that have been processed (and of course, it's not possible to view the transaction IDs of rows that haven't been processed, because, well, they wouldn't have transactions IDs yet :) ).

This is a great idea for a new feature of MassPay.  I've added it to our to-do list.

In the mean time, I recommend another solution: capture and store all TransactionStatus webhook notifications, and then wait until the job is complete before attempting to correlate them.  Once the job is complete, you will have access to those transaction IDs and can correlate the transaction statuses back to each row.